# Slider using MMDrawerController is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

I have a `ViewController` and its xib file contains a `UIBarButtonItem`. I want to achieve facebook like slider menu when I tap this `UIBarButtonItem` and for this I am using `MMDrawer`. I have written a method and connected this to the barButtonItem. However this functionality is not working. The code of the method is :

```
leftSideDrawerViewController = [[SliderMenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SliderMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
centerViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil];

drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]initWithCenterViewController:centerViewController leftDrawerViewController:leftSideDrawerViewController];
[drawerController setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMDrawer"];

[drawerController setMaximumLeftDrawerWidth:200];
[drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
[drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
```

I am not using Storyboard. Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrote code to Initialize `MMDrawController` with Left , Right and Center View Controllers.
You have to add `UIBarButton` and create MMDrawController Object in `centerViewController`. and connect below method.

Open LeftView

```
-(void)leftDrawerButtonPress:(id)sender
{
    [self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Can you show full code when you initialize MMDraw and where you bind Methods?

Comment: If I write the code to initialize MMDrawerController and the above method in any ViewController, it throws sigabrt error.

Comment: I have a UIBarButtonItem in a SampleViewController where I declared the method as you suggested and bind it to the UIBarButtonItem.

Now, In the viewDidLoad method of the MainMenuViewController which is my centerviewController, I wrote the code to initialize the MMDrawerController.

Comment: You have to write Initialization code in `ViewController`. and add this method `leftDrawerButtonPress` with the answer in `MainMenuViewController`.

Comment: Your flow will be `SampleViewController` initialize mmdraw here and push `MMDraw` using `self.navigationcontroller`. then Create Barbutton in `MainMenuViewController` and bind method.

Comment: @abhhab did you get me?

Comment: I did not get the concept of self.navigationcontroller. I did as you directed but I am getting either sigabrt error or BadAccess error.

Comment: I have written the leftDrawerButtonPress method with its content in the SampleViewController and created a BarButtonItem and connected these two. 
In the viewDidLoad method of SampleViewController, I initialized the MMDrawer, I get the sigabrt error.
When I initialize the MMdrawer in MenuViewController, I get the BadAccess error.